# joins vs distributed cache in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

what is the difference between joins and distributed cache in hadoop. I am really confusing with map-side join and reduce-side join an dhow it works. how distributed cache is different while processing the data in mapreduce job. Please share with example.
Regards,
Ravi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have 2 files of data with the following records:

word -> frequency

Same words can be present in both files.
Your task is to merge these files, compute total frequency for each term, and produce the aggregated file.

**Map side joins.**

Useful when your data on both sides of the join already presorted by keys. In this case, it is a simple merge of two streams with linear complexity. In our example, our word-frequency data have to be pre-sorted alphabetically by words in both files.

*Pros:* works with virtually unlimited input data (does not have to fit in memory). 
Does not require a reducer, thus it is very efficient.

*Cons:* requires your input data to be pre-sorted (for example, as a result of a previous map/reduce job)

**Reduce joins.**

Useful when our files are not sorted yet, and they are too large to fit in memory. So you have to merge them using distributed sort with reducer(s).

*Pros:* works with virtually unlimited input data (does not have to fit in memory).

*Cons:* requires reduce phase

**Distributed cache.**

Useful when our input word-frequency files are NOT sorted, and one of two files is small enough to fit in memory. In this case you can use it as a distributed cache, and load it in memory as a hash table Map<String, Integer>. Each mapper than will stream the largest input file as key value pairs and look up the values of the smaller file from the hash map.

*Pros:* Efficient, linear complexity based on largest input set size. Does not require reducer.

*Cons:* Requires one of the inputs to fit in memory.